# Função que converte dólares para reais, pesos mexicanos e pesos chilenos

Tags: javascript, funções

Escreva uma função com o nome `coinConverter` que converte o valor de dólares para reais, pesos mexicanos e pesos chilenos.

Use as seguintes taxas de câmbio:

```
reais = dólares * 3.25 // 
pesosMexicanos = dólares * 18 // pesosChilenos = dólares * 660
```

Código:

```
module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  var arr = [];
  var reais = [usDollars * 3.25];
  var mexicanPesos = [usDollars * 18];
  var chileanPesos = [usDollars * 660];

  // Adicione o valor equivalente em reais
  arr.push(50*3.25);

  // Adicione o valor equivalente em pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(50*18);

  // Adicione o valor equivalente em pesos chilenos
  arr.push(50*660);

  return arr;
};
```

Coloco os dados e somente um fica com Ok...E aparece este erro:

```
coinConvert()
```

- deveria devolver `[162.5, 900, 33000]`, para `$50`, ok
- deveria devolver `[325, 1800, 66000]`, para `$100`
- expected `[ 162.5, 900, 33000 ]` to deeply equal `[ 325, 1800, 66000 ]`
- deveria devolver `[243.75, 1350, 49500]`, para `$85`
- expected `[ 162.5, 900, 33000 ]` to deeply equal `[ 276.25, 1530, 56100 ]`

Comment: Olá @Jeh, observe no seu código que o valor "50" está fixo quando executa o `array.push()`, ou seja, voce deve trocar o valor "50" de acordo com as variaveis criadas acima. Voce criou 3 (reais, mexicanPesos e chileanPesos), só que nao fez nada com elas.

Comment: Mas como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já esta fazendo os cálculos que o exercício pede:

```
var reais = [usDollars * 3.25];
var mexicanPesos = [usDollars * 18];
var chileanPesos = [ usDollars * 660 ];
/// ;              ^                 ^
/// ; você não precisa usar array aqui
```

Você só precisa colocar esses valores dentro da sua variável `arr` ao invés de usar o valor fixo. Então seu código deve ficar +/- como no exemplo abaixo:

```
module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  var arr = [];
  var reais = usDollars * 3.25;
  var mexicanPesos = usDollars * 18;
  var chileanPesos = usDollars * 660;
  ///  ; NOTE que aqui eu removi o array `[]` 

  //arr.push(50*3.25);
  arr.push(reais);
  /// ;     ^ tire o valor fixo e coloque sua variável que esta fazendo o calculo 

  //arr.push(50*18);
  arr.push(mexicanPesos);
  /// ;     ^ mesma coisa aqui

  //arr.push(50*660); 
  arr.push(chileanPesos);
  /// ;     ^ mesma coisa aqui

  return arr;
};
```

Veja sua função em execução:

```js
function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  var arr = [];
  var reais = usDollars * 3.25;
  var mexicanPesos = usDollars * 18;
  var chileanPesos = usDollars * 660;
  ///  ; NOTE que aqui eu removi o array `[]` 

  arr.push(reais);
  /// ;     ^ mudei aki

  arr.push(mexicanPesos);
  /// ;     ^ mudei aki

  arr.push(chileanPesos);
  /// ;     ^ mudei aki

  return arr;
};

let v = prompt("Entre com o valor");
v = parseFloat(v);
if( isNaN(v) ) v = 0;

alert( coinConvert( v ) );
```

Comment: Obrigada Icaro!

Answer (score 0):

Jeh, você está utilizando uma constante para multiplicar pela taxa de câmbio, por isso o seu valor está sempre igual!
Para resolver seu problema, você deve utilizar a variável que esta sendo recebida na função, que no seu caso é `usDollars`.

```
  // Adicione o valor equivalente em reais
  arr.push(usDollars*3.25);

  // Adicione o valor equivalente em pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(usDollars*18);

  // Adicione o valor equivalente em pesos chilenos
  arr.push(usDollars*660);
```

Sendo assim, esta parte do código não tem função alguma, e pode ser apagada, pois você não estará utilizando, e retorna apenas o array `arr`:

```
  var reais = [usDollars * 3.25];
  var mexicanPesos = [usDollars * 18];
  var chileanPesos = [usDollars * 660];
```

Comment: Obrigada Pedro!